# Wubi ubuntu 12.04 install upgrade to full

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, wubi

I used [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop. It had Windows XP on it and the DVD drive died. And I would like to migrate to Ubuntu. So I used Wubi. But it seems that wubi installs ubuntu on a virtual hard drive. 
So I tried a reinstall with [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on my 8gb USB drive. But the machine is so old that it cannot boot from USB.

So that is my current scenario, and I would like to know if I can upgrade my Wubi install to a full install. No dual boot. Format the whole drive etc. 
All resources on the net use a CD or DVD drive. Which does not work for me. I have an USB Wifi dongle which I used to download and install Wubi from within Win XP. I also have a windows bootloader and afterwards grub bootloader :S

p.s. I have found [this guide](http://flip.netzbeben.de/2008/08/move-wubi-installation-ubuntu-on-windows-to-a-native-ubuntu-system/), is this the recommended option for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this seems like it could do the  trick for you. Just make sure to change directory to your 'Downloads' folder before doing the wget command. Otherwise you won't be able to run the script as explained in the walkthrough. To do this type

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

after that just follow the steps in the instruction.

Comment: Ok, thanks will try and update this thread a.s.a.p.